# Transferring save data for Sea of Thieves from an internal hard-drive to an external hard drive (Xbox One)

Tags: xbox-one, sea-of-thieves

I was wondering if it would be possible for me to move the save data from the internal hard-drive onto a hard drive. I have the disk for the game, but i want to move the data to an external hard drive. Any information would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Which game is this for?  I don't think save games can exist on discs; they're usually read-only.

Comment: Sorry if the question was a bit unclear, I want to try and move a safe for  Sea of Thieves from a disc onto an external hard-drive.

Comment: Okay, right game, but we still need more info; how are you playing this?  On Xbox?

Comment: I am currently playing on Xbox

Comment: Alright.  Are you aware that save games don't exist on discs, but on the internal hard drive?  If you still want to know if it can be moved to an external drive, I'd recommend updating your question.

Comment: Okay, now that the question has changed, is there anyway for the save game to be moved from the internal hard-drive to the external-hard drive?

Comment: Excellent!  Now that you've clarified, someone will be able to answer.  You'll need to be patient, though.

Comment: Thanks for being patient, and giving me help on what information I need to provide

Answer (score 3):

Sea of Thieves does not store savegame data locally. Everything is stored on servers. I can play on my Xbox, and pick up right where I left off on another Xbox or my PC, and vice versa.

The only exception to this might be configuration type of data (e.g. graphics settings, keybinds, etc) and as far as I know, those types of files are (basically) impossible to manually manage and move. At least, its impossible using a stock Xbox with built in GUI. Its probably possible with some modification or a custom ROM, but that is far past the scope of this question.

If you are deadset on getting your savegame data onto an external hard drive (for "reasons") it is impossible without "hacking" and breaking the EULA. MS specifically prohibited and prevented this back in the Xbox 360 days since it could be used to develop cheats and obtain achievements.

I wholly believe your motivation is innocuous, and in that case, I cannot imagine a need to get your savegame data onto an external hard drive. If you provide some additional details regarding your end goal, we may uncover an [X Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)